# PHP changing password and it's not working. There is no error with the syntax I believe, but the password won't change

Tags: php, mysqli, error-handling

I'm making a php file called changepassword.php and the sole purpose of the file is to allow the user to change their password. However, when they go through the form to change their password the box fields clear and I receive my echo warning echo "A Password Box was Left Empty!". This does not want to seem to update the user's password and I have no clue what do. I am new to this language so don't expect much. I would greatly appreciate some constructive input to help me code php better.

```
<?php
session_start(); 
#error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once('connect.php');
require_once "lib.php";
require_once "utils.php";

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_SESSION['active']===true)
{
    if(!empty($_POST['OldPassword'])&&
        !empty($_POST['NewPassword'])&&
        !empty($_POST['NewPassword1']))
    {
        $OldPassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,htmlentities($_POST['OldPassword']));
        $NewPassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,htmlentities($_POST['NewPassword']));
        $NewPassword1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,htmlentities($_POST['NewPassword1']));

        $EmailAdress = $_SESSION['EmailAdress'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE EmailAddress='$EmailAddress'";

        if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql))
        {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
            {
                $temp1=$row['Password'];
                if($row['Password'] != $OldPassword)
                {
                    echo "<div id='change_error1'>* This Does Not Match Previous Password!<br></div>";
                }
            }

            if($NewPassword != $NewPassword1)
            {
                echo "<div id='change_error2'>* You Passwords DO NOT Match!</div>";
            }

            if($temp1 == $OldPassword && $NewPassword == $NewPassword1)
            {
                $sql = "UPDATE users SET Password='$NewPassword' WHERE EmailAddress='$EmailAddress'";
                if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql))
                {
                    header("Location: profile.php");
                    echo "<strong>YOURE PASSWORD HAS BEEN UPDATED!</strong>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<div id='change_error3'>A Password Box was Left Empty!</div>";
    }
}
?>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Change Password</title>
   </head>
   <br></br>
   <br></br>
   <body class="body">
      <div id="wrapper">
         <div id="header">
            <br>
            <h1> PHP Learning Course </h1>
            <br>
            <?php require_once "left.php" ?>
         </div>
         <div id="change">
            <div id="change_name">
               <h3> Change Password</h3>
            </div>
            <p>
            <div id='change_form'>
               <form action='changepass.php' method='POST'>
                  Old Password:<br> <input name='OldPassword' type='password'/></br>
                  <br>
                  New Password:<br> <input name='NewPassword' type='password'/></br>
                  <br>
                  Confirm Password:<br> <input name='newpass1' type='password'/></br>
                  <br>
                  <input name='submit' type='submit' value='Change Password' />
               </form>
               </p>
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- end main div -->
      </div>
      <!-- end wrapper div -->
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($link))` to `mysqli_query()`. You'll see the error.

Comment: Undefined variable: temp1 on line 38;     Undefined variable: EmailAddress on line 19 & 20. I'm stuck now.

Comment: There you go. Now you know what to go after and to fix it; define them. Someone gave you an answer below also. You can ask them. I'm off to lah-lah land.

Comment: Could you elaborate where?

Comment: starting from line 20, goto line 1 backwards. the error inside these 20 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 !empty($_POST['NewPassword1']))
```

index should be, `newpass1`

i.e. `!empty($_POST['newpass1']))`

because in the form, you have put,

```
 Confirm Password:<br> <input name='newpass1' type='password'/></br>
```

stick with one convention to avoid these errors.

Comment: lol it was a syntax error right there, but now the new password isn't being updated in the database.

Comment: your password isn't being updated because the code flow goes into `else` block. correct this and it will be updated provided you have correct sql.